# Fft windowing in Python, choice and optimisation

Tags: python, fft, windowing

I'm currently trying to calculate THD, noise floor and other audio measurement (IMD, frequency response with Python). To do so, i'm importing wave file into numpy array, then calculating the fft with scipy modules. To avoid aliasing, I need to window my data before doing my fft. So I try to compare different window, and here is some result (997 kHz sine, 32bits, 192 kHz generated by adobe audition)  :

[image]

[image]

I'm looking for precision : the noise floor should be as low as possible, and the response outside the peak as flat as possible. So my question is : is Rife-Vincent the really best option I have ? Did I miss other "secret" window that I don't know and didn't test ?

If I decide to keep the Rife-Vincent window, the problem is time calculation ! The others windows are implemented in the scipy module and are very fast to calculate. I calculate the Rife-Vincent coefficients like this :

```
w = np.empty(M,dtype=np.float64)
a = 2*np.pi/M
for i in np.arange(0, M):
    w[i] = (35 - 56*np.cos(a*i) + 28*np.cos(2*a*i) - 8*np.cos(3*a*i) + np.cos(4*a*i))/128
```

Where M is my data length, which can be quite long. This is very time consuming, can anyone help me to optimize it ?

Comment: What do "997 kHz sine, 192 kHz" mean?

Comment: A pure sine @ 997 Hz (that was the mistake, sorry about that ;) ) sampled at 192 kHz.

Answer (score 0):

To answer how to compute the window:

```
a = 2*np.pi/M
x = np.arange(0, M)
w = (35 - 56 * np.cos(a * x) + 28 * np.cos(2 * a * x) - 8 * np.cos(3 * a * x) + np.cos(4 * a * x))/128
```

should be pretty fast. You could save yourself some temporary variables by doing this:

```
w = 35 - 56 * np.cos(a * x)
w +=  28 * np.cos(2 * a * x)
w -= 8 * np.cos(3 * a * x)
w += np.cos(4 * a * x)
w /= 128.
```

but it will only save you 1 s in about 7 for 3e7 points.

If you want it faster, you should use numexpr:

```
w = ne.evaluate('(35 - 56 * cos(a * x) + 28 * cos(2 * a * x) - 8 * cos(3 * a * x) + cos(4 * a * x))/128')
```

that will compile and compute it in parallel; on my computer the time goes from 7 to 2 s.

Comment: Thanks a lot, it is a very good improvement ! 
Is it also possible to reduce the loading time of module such as matplotlib (~2s) and Scipy ?

Comment: @NessyW. that is another question. But the truth is, it shouldn't take so long. On my box, MPL loads in 250 ms, and scipy in 80. Don't forget to add to your question your OS and how were they installed.

Comment: My question was not well formulated I admit. I actually wanted to ask, is it normal that it takes so long (I'm working on a Raspberry Pi :)) ?
BTW, I was too quick testing your numepxr method : it is faster, but it does not give me the same result ^^ I'm working on it and will come back when I find the reason why...

Comment: Oh, then there is little you can do except patching your own numpy and reduce the things you do at import. For example, you could disable the testing module.